# std::ofstream can't save text file?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, fstream

I cannot save a textfile with c++. It goes through the code with no error.  My OS is Windows 11 (22H2). C++ and the g++ compiler have both version 12.1.0.

What I've tried:

- checking with debugger, but no error was found
- deactivated Firewall and any other antivirus software
- checked folder rights, and run the .exe as admin
- restarted the computer

My code should be OK, otherwise my previous efforts where unnecessary:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream MyFile("./test.txt");
    MyFile << "Test";
    MyFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never check if the file opened successfully or not. And if it succeeds, then the file might not be saved in the location you expect.

Comment: First of all, try `ofstream MyFile("./test.txt"); if (MyFile) { MyFile << "Test\n"; MyFile.close(); } else { cout << "Failed to open file\n"; }`

Comment: you can check `std::filesystem::current_path`

Comment: Also make sure that the [Current Working Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is where you think it is.

Comment: You don't need to call `MyFile.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: Regarding the above comment, this is an example of a bit of C++ magic called [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii). The constructor acquires the resource, the file in this case, and the destructor releases it. RAII allows you to automate many otherwise complicated management tasks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the file doesn't saved successfully. But the directory is the right one. Idk why it is not saved.

Comment: Do you mean that the file is created, but it's empty without text inside it? Then how do you check its contents? And when do you check the contents? Also, if you remove the file and run the program again, is the file recreated (but empty)?

Comment: @TrueStoryShort if you are *sure* the **current working directory** is what you are expecting (since you are using a *relative* path instead of an *absolute* path), then most likely you simply don't have write permissions to that directory, or write permissions to that specific file (ie, maybe it is already open somewhere else?)

Comment: @TrueStoryShort: Does it print the error message `"Failed to open file\n"` when you change the code to what was recommended to you?

Comment: @RemyLebeau  the file isn't created. I've also doublechecked the directory. It should be also no problem with writepermissions which i also assumed at first. I've checked the folder permissions, run the exe as admin, and closed other possible troubleshooters like antivirus

Comment: @TrueStoryShort "*the file isn't created*" - Then I suggest you ask Windows why it fails. What does `GetLastError()` report? You might have to use `CreateFile()` directly to get a reliable error code, at least for testing until you fix the root cause

Comment: Well i've found the solution thx @RemyLebeau and all others. It's because ive opened the file in vs code. Normaly (with other languages) i don't had a problem with that. Well such an easy problem took me literally 2 hours...